# Quickblox custom object push to array string that contain : ' , ' or ' " '

Tags: java, android, quickblox, custom-object

this is my code:

```
String comment = newComment.getText().toString();
...

fields.put("push[array][]", comment);
```

now, it's work well , but if the string "comment" contain for example: **' , ' (comma) -   ("dsa,dsa")**.

on the server it's become two variables: **[dsa , dsa]**.

another example: if the string "comment" contain: **' " ' (qoute) - ("dsa "dsa" dsa")**.

on the server it's : **[dsa \dsa\ dsa]**.

how to fix it?

Comment: I am not familiar with quickblox api but does it fix it self when you try to get it back?  For the quote case try escaping the quote in the actual string so if you have "dsa "dsa" dsa"  use  "dsa \"dsa\" dsa"

Comment: thanks, it doesn't fix it self, i'v tried this for the quote case - doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try dsa%2Cdsa ?

Comment: thanks, i will try it, but what to do with quote?

Comment: it's doesnt fix it self, so ur solution is to replace all problematic characters to somthing else - 
comment.replaceAll(",", "%2C"); - and back when return it from quickblox?
do you know what are all the problematic characters?

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [document](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=96) for more details.